# Find substrings in string where substring encapsulated in specific character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string in the format:

```
"The quick __grey__ fox jumps over the lazy __brown__ dog."
```

And I want to find and replace any words (or sometimes sentences) between the double underscores.

I am currently using preg_match_all in PHP:

```
$pattern = '/__(.*)__/';
```

This works fine... until it finds two sets of double underscores on the same line, such as in the above example, where it matches "__grey__" and "__brown__" as I want, but also "__grey__ fox jumps over the lazy brown__", which I do not want...

So my question is is there a way of matching only between the first and second instance, the third and fourth instance, etc?

I apologise if this has been asked before, but I'm really not sure how to phrase the question in a way concise enough to perform a useful search!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$pattern = '/__(.*?)__/';` - use lazy matching. Thousands of such questions have been asked.

Comment: Thankyou!  I was sure it wouldn't be a unique question, but if you don't already know the answer it's very difficult to find the right kind of question :(

Comment: I will post a community wiki answer. Can't find a good relevant post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find some substring between two closest identical delimiters, use lazy dot matching:

```
$pattern = '/__(.*?)__/';
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV4eP7/1)

To also match newlines, use `/s` modifier:

```
$pattern = '/__(.*?)__/s';
```

Comment: Perfect, thankyou!  I will accept this as soon as the timer allows me :)

Comment: It does not matter, I do not get any reputation points for this. But please accept.

Comment: Yeah, go tell that to [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). :)